# Kotlin nullable variable assignment

Tags: kotlin, variable-assignment, shortcut, kotlin-null-safety

In Kotlin, is there any shorter syntax for this code:

```
if(swipeView == null){
     swipeView = view.find<MeasureTypePieChart>(R.id.swipeableView)
}
```

First i tried this:

```
 swipeView ?: view.find<MeasureTypePieChart>(R.id.swipeableView)
```

but then i realised that wasn't an assignment, so that code does nothing. Then i tried:

```
swipeView = swipeView ?: view.find<MeasureTypePieChart>(R.id.swipeableView)
```

Which works, but it a bit verbose. I would expect something like this:

```
swipeView ?= view.find<MeasureTypePieChart>
```

But unfortunately that doesn't work. Is there any way of accomplish this with a short syntax?

I know i can do this:

```
variable?.let { it = something } which works.
```

Comment: `variable?.let { it = something }` does not work. It assigns `something` to `variable` only if `variable` is _not_ null.

Comment: Idk your use case, but lazy delegate can be useful in similar cases https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy

Comment: Not advisable, but here's a one liner for that
`swipeView = swipeView ?: view.find<MeasureTypePieChart>(R.id.swipeableView).apply { swipeView = this }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shorter syntax would be to avoid `swipeView` from ever being `null`.

### Local variable

If `swipeView` is a local variable then you can declare it non-null when initially assigning it:

```
val swipeView = ... ?: view.find<MeasureTypePieChart>(R.id.swipeableView)
```

### Function argument

If `swipeView` is a function argument then you can use a [default argument](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#default-arguments) to ensure it is never `null`:

```
fun something(swipeView: View = view.find<MeasureTypePieChart>(R.id.swipeableView))
```

### Class property

#### Read-only

If `swipeView` is a read-only class property (i.e. `val`) then you can use Kotlin's built-in [`Lazy`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy):

```
val swipeView by lazy { view.find<MeasureTypePieChart>(R.id.swipeableView) }
```

#### Mutable

If `swipeView` is a mutable class property (i.e. `var`) then you can define your own delegate similar to `Lazy` but mutable. e.g. The following is based on [kotlin/Lazy.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/07de81937720f1327499fdfdd480bec23bd828a6/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Lazy.kt):

```
interface MutableLazy<T> : Lazy<T> {
    override var value: T
}

fun <T> mutableLazy(initializer: () -> T): MutableLazy<T> = SynchronizedMutableLazyImpl(initializer)

fun <T> mutableLazy(lock: Any?, initializer: () -> T): MutableLazy<T> = SynchronizedMutableLazyImpl(initializer, lock)

operator fun <T> MutableLazy<T>.getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T = value
operator fun <T> MutableLazy<T>.setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
    this.value = value
}

private object UNINITIALIZED_VALUE

private class SynchronizedMutableLazyImpl<T>(initializer: () -> T, lock: Any? = null) : MutableLazy<T>, Serializable {
    private var initializer: (() -> T)? = initializer
    @Volatile private var _value: Any? = UNINITIALIZED_VALUE
    // final field is required to enable safe publication of constructed instance
    private val lock = lock ?: this

    override var value: T
        get() {
            val _v1 = _value
            if (_v1 !== UNINITIALIZED_VALUE) {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                return _v1 as T
            }

            return synchronized(lock) {
                val _v2 = _value
                if (_v2 !== UNINITIALIZED_VALUE) {
                    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") (_v2 as T)
                } else {
                    val typedValue = initializer!!()
                    _value = typedValue
                    initializer = null
                    typedValue
                }
            }
        }
        set(value) {
            val _v1 = _value
            if (_v1 !== UNINITIALIZED_VALUE) {
                _value = value
            } else synchronized(lock) {
                _value = value
                initializer = null
            }
        }

    override fun isInitialized(): Boolean = _value !== UNINITIALIZED_VALUE

    override fun toString(): String = if (isInitialized()) value.toString() else "MutableLazy value not initialized yet."
}
```

Usage:

```
var swipeView by mutableLazy { view.find<MeasureTypePieChart>(R.id.swipeableView) }
```

The `initializer` will only be called if `swipeView` is read and is not initialized yet (from a previous read or write).